# Check if block is called in phtml file

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, custom, phtml, price-rules

Is it possible to check in `default.phtml` file (app\design\frontend\MyNAMESpace\MY_THEME\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\price\amount\default.phtml) that `catalog.product.related` (block ) is loaded or not?

I want to add condition in `default.phtml` file if `default.phtml` file is called in `catalog.product.related` | `product.info.upsell`

I am curious to know if this can be possible in any method.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code :

```
<?php

//$instruction = "container";
//$instruction = "referenceContainer";
$instruction = "block";
//$instruction = "referenceBlock";

$path = '/var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento';
$command = 'cd '.$path.' && egrep -r -i --include \*.xml "<'.$instruction.'".*?"name=" *';
exec($command, $output);

$container_max_length = 1;
$pattern = '/(.*?):.*<'.$instruction.'.*name="(.*?)".*/';
foreach ($output as $subject) {
  preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
  $containers[$matches[2]][] = $matches[1];
  if (strlen($matches[2]) > $container_max_length) $container_max_length = strlen($matches[2]);
}

$n=1;
ksort($containers);
foreach ($containers as $k => $v) {
  printf("%6s", "$n. ");
  printf("%-".$container_max_length."s".$v[0]."\n", $k);
  $i=1;
  while (isset($v[$i])) {
    printf("      %-".$container_max_length."s".$v[$i]."\n", "");
    $i++;
  }
  $n++;
}

?>
```

**hope it is helpful to you**